# Best practice: family of classes with various type of configuration class

Tags: java

I am defining a family of classes used to get data from different sources (from example, a class will get data from a database, another one from a file, etc.)
Since the data sources are so different, there is no common interface for their configurations.
They all share a common method `getData()` though.

The idea was to define a set of predefined configurations (most of the time, the configurations used will just depend on a locale, thus there would one configuration for usa, one for france, etc.).

I have create the interface:

```
public interface IDataSource {
    public void initialize(Object config);
    public List<String> getData();
}
```

And the class DataSourceA:

```
public class DataSourceA implements IDataSource {
    public void initialize(Object config) {
        DataSourceAConfig configA = (DataSourceAConfig) config;
        initializeA(configA);
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        ...
    }

    private void initializeA(DataSourceAConfig config) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and DataSourceB:

```
public class DataSourceB implements IDataSource {
    public void initialize(Object config) {
        DataSourceBConfig configB = (DataSourceBConfig) config;
        initializeB(configB);
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        ...
    }

    private void initializeA(DataSourceBConfig config) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am not happy with that solution (for example, using `initialize(Object config)`, then cast the config). I am looking for advice on how to rethink the problem.

Edit:
I generated the configuration implementations using jaxb. Then the user would have to pass the type of data source and the name of the configuration file to the data source factory to get the data source.

Comment: What do your configs contain? If it's only strings we could consider something using a map.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. Unfortunately, it would probably have to come down to using a Map<String, Object>. Since for some of the configuration elements will be complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an interface(abstract class) like `DataSourceConfig`. `DataSourceAConfig` and `DataSourceBConfig` will implement(extend) it. In your `initialize` method, you can replace `Object` with `DataSourceConfig`.

If your datasources are so different, you should change the IDataSource too:

```
public interface IDataSource<T extends DataSourceConfig> {
    public void initialize(T config);
    public List<String> getData();
}
```

DataSourceConfig will be the common interface and DataSourceB will implement IDataSource like this:

```
public class DataSourceB implements IDataSource<DataSourceBConfig> {
    public void initialize(DataSourceBConfig config) {
        initializeB(config);
    }
    // everything else omitted for simplicity
}
```

Comment: Thought of that too but I don't think it's much of an improvement if both implementation of the datasource don't have anything in common. You would still have to cast. Only advantage is a better restriction on the objects you can hand over to `initialize()`.

Comment: It should have something in common, it's a datasource, after all, it should behave in a similar way so the cast won't be necessary in my opinion. After all, you should use programming to interface. You should don't care about implementation.

Comment: Example: A datasource pointing to a file and one pointing to a database. The config for the first one has a path. The other one has an URI, a user, a password an maybe some other connection parameters. What would your interface look like?

Comment: `public Connection getConnection(URI address, Map<String, String> connParams)` ?

Comment: Point taken, would be the way to go for my example ;-) That's why I already asked OP if using a map might be possible. If not all parameters are strings we would end up using `Map<String, Object>` which also isn't pretty. Anyway, I think how such an interface would look like is the essence of this question so you should include it in your answer.

Comment: I could define a common interface but it would have to contain getUsername, getPassword, etc. that would be used exclusively for the database data source and also getRegex, getFileName(), etc. that would be used exclusively by the file data source. That does not sound right...

Comment: What about this: `public interface IDataSource<T extends DataSourceConfig>`. `DataSourceConfig` will be the common interface and `DataSourceB` will implement `IDataSource<DataSourceBConfig>`. Still no casting.

Comment: Yes, I guess I could use a marker interface for the configuration. But then every reference to a data source would have to be IDataSource<?>: for example the factory signature would be public IDataSource<?> getDataSource(String dataSourceId, DataSourceConfig config); Not sure if that's a big deal though.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it seems to fit your needs :)